# Power Supply amp doesn't match with adapter. Can I use the adapter?

Tags: voltage, lcd, display, amperage, adapter

Can I use this LCD display: http://www.itontec.com/product-detail/product-name-7/

With this adapter:

[image]

*Display Specs: Power Supply(5~12V 2A)

*Adapter Specs: Output: 12V - 1A

Is that safe to use this adapter with this display?

Comment: Think about it again. The display wants 2A, the adapter can supply 1A. What do you think will the adapter do?

Comment: I don't know. I'm very ignorant about electronics. I'm trying to learn. What happens if I use this adapter with this display?

Comment: From reading the specs provided above, it appears as if the monitor wants somewhat less than 10 Watts of power. Assuming that the monitor has a switch mode power supply internally (good assumption because the monitor would have to somehow get rid 14 Watts of heat with a 12 Vdc input), a power supply input of 12 Vdc should also have to supply about 10 Watts.  That's less than 1 Amp.

Comment: @DwayneReid I tried to use adapter with display one hour age and it's working fine. I think it's draining less than 1 Amp yeah you right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather not. The specs of your display say that it *might* need 2A at times, and this would overload your adapter. This means that its voltage drops and the adapter might heat up, or break in the long run.

There's a chance those 2A spec are for the lower end of the voltage (5V) and it will pull less for 12V, but that would only be the case if you see a switching DC/DC regulator on the PCB. If it's a linear regulator, it will take 2A and just convert the extra voltage to heat.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe yes, maybe no.  You will have to try it and see.

Because the monitor says "5-12V 2A", there is a very good chance that the monitor has a switch-mode supply internally.  That would cause the monitor to consume about 2 Amps with a 5 Vdc input (10 Watts) but consume less than 1 Amp with a 12 Vdc input (also about 10 Watts).

The only way to find out for sure is to try it.

If it *doesn't* work, no damage should occur to either the power supply or monitor.  It just won't work.

My best guess is that it will work just fine.

Comment: Overloading the wall wart power supply by 100%? I wouldn't try. It might break or -- if it's a cheap one -- melt/smell/burn.

Comment: @DerManu Is there a risk for damage to the display?

Comment: @mertyildiran: Very unlikely. It might "brown out", i.e. controllers might reset due to low voltage. In electronics as simple as displays that usually is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @DerManu Okay then the safest solution is using 12v 2a power supply. Am I correct?

Comment: @mertyildiran: Yes. 2A or greater will be fine.